# Entity Update is not working, no error in update process.

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

There is no error and newUser object is found on database but database is not modified. Whats the problem. As new learner, elaborate answer is much appreciated. thanks.

```
TBL_LogIn newUser = new TBL_LogIn();
newUser = hrmsDb.TBL_LogIn.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == inputEmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();
try
{
    if (newUser != null)
    {
        AddLogInInfo(newUser);
        hrmsDb.Entry(newUser).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        hrmsDb.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    { }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}

/*-----Functions to Update New Employee Information in Three tables-------*/
private void AddLogInInfo(TBL_LogIn newUser)
{
    string UserName = TextBoxUsername.Text;
    string Password = TextBoxPassword.Text;
    string UserType = TextBoxUserType.Text;

    newUser.UserName = UserName;
    newUser.PassWord = Password;
    newUser.UserType = UserType;
}
```

Comment: Does your code reach inside **if statement**? In other words, make sure `newUser != null` is true.

Comment: `AddLogInInfo` updates existing record?

Comment: Yes my code reach inside the **if statement** and then go to **AddLogInInfo()** function . I made sure that `newUser != null` is true. @Win .  Yes,**AddLogInInfo** updates existing record @Mathew

Comment: `hrmsDb.Entry(newUser).State = EntityState.Modified;` is not needed unless you retrieved the object `AsNoTracking()` or `context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`  If either of these are true, you need to attach the object back to the context, then set the modified state.

Comment: If you post and people take time to understand and answer your question the least you can do is say how you fixed it, might even want to thank people for their time.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new. Don't know where to say how I solved the problem, in comment or will I add answer to my own question? @AdamHeeg . The problem was `TBL_LogIn newUser = new TBL_LogIn();` setting **newUser** not null all the time, even when entity is not found. I added `TBL_LogIn newUser = newUser = hrmsDb.TBL_LogIn.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == inputEmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();` and it solved my problem. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if either of these is causing the problem but you shouldn't be creating a new object when you're just going to retrieve into the variable on the next line and it should not be necessary to set the state of the object, EF should take care of that for you.

```
TBL_LogIn newUser = hrmsDb.TBL_LogIn.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == inputEmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

if (newUser != null)
{
    AddLogInInfo(newUser);
    hrmsDb.SaveChanges();
}
else
{ }
```

P.S. If all you're going to do in the catch block is rethrow the exception don't bother putting in a try/catch because that's what will happen anyway.